# Symfony and Heroku worker: can I use the database as communication mechanism between the front-end and the background worker?

Tags: php, heroku, background-process

I need an [Heroku's Worker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) to do some background tasks.

Now, reading the article *Background jobs with workers in PHP*, I found that [the architecture designed in the article makes use of RabbitMQ](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-workers#basic-architecture) as messaging system between the web dyno and the worker dyno.

But I don't want to use RabbitMQ as it is really too much complex at this stage.

So, as communication mechanism between `web dyno` and `worker dyno`, I'd like to use one of these two alternatives:

1. Simply the database (largely my best choice :P)
2. AWS SQS (I can use it, but the database would be better for my needs)

Now, the example provided [using RabbitMQ](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-workers#worker-process) uses a callback to make the script alive and continously receive new messages in the queue:

```
$callback = function($msg) use($app) {
    $app['monolog']->debug('New task received for censoring message: ' . $msg->body);

    try {
        // call the "censor" API and pass it the text to clean up
        $result = $app['guzzle']->get('censor', ['query' => ['corpus' => $msg->body]]);
        $result = json_decode($result->getBody());
        if($result) {
            $app['monolog']->debug('Censored message result is: ' . $result->censored_text);
            // store in Redis
            $app['predis']->lpush('opinions', $result->censored_text);
            // mark as delivered in RabbitMQ
            $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
        } else {
            $app['monolog']->warning('Failed to decode JSON, will retry later');
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $app['monolog']->warning('Failed to call API, will retry later');
    }
};

$channel->basic_qos(null, 1, null);
$channel->basic_consume('task_queue', '', false, false, false, false, $callback);

// loop over incoming messages
while(count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}
```

My question is: how can I "emulate" the `$channel->wait()` command without using RabbitMQ?

**In other words, how can I make the `worker dyno` able to read the queue from the database or from the AWS SQS, continously, starting processing the messages as they appears in the database or in the AWS SQS queue?**

<del>Should have I to use a scheduled job using [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) that starts the dyno?</del> (Not applicable: see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#long-running-jobs) why).

Or there is another flow that I'm not considering?

Or, more, maybe creating a [symfony command line app](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/single_command_tool.html) based on the front-end app is the definitive solution? Will it run without stopping?

Comment: I think you must use Symfony Command-line Application, you can define that in Heroku like a ruby script : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#defining-tasks

Comment: Why using "AWS SQS queue" ?

Comment: Why not? Anyway because I'm already using other AWS services...

Comment: Anyway I'm already using the scheduler: the problem, here, is that I'd like to have a background process that listens in almost real time, exactly as does the worker in the example provided by Heroku. But the problem is that that example uses RabbitMQ.

Comment: Listen the database or make requests to an another service ?

Comment: That listens the "queue", independently by the fact is is RabbitMQ, AWS SQS or the database.

Comment: Loool, I do not really understand your problem!

Comment: Why you don't understand? If you reply me this way maybe I'm having a problem that doesn't exist in the reality. This means also that there is something I'm missing. Can you write an answer where you explain me the flow you imagine and how it solves my problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129018/discussion-between-mathieu-dormeval-and-aerendir).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Heroku PostgreSQL (for example), you could have your worker process listen on [asynchronous notifications](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-notify.html), that you could have coming from the database by creating appropriate triggers.

See [this nice post on Postgres Pub-Sub features](https://blog.andyet.com/2015/04/06/postgres-pubsub-with-json/) for details.

So, your web dyno can insert or update records in the database, which can automatically trigger notifications to your worker dyno.

Your worker dyno runs forever, and simply listens on the notification channel, processing any messages it receives.

If you are using a different database, it may or may not have similar capabilities. But this is definitely doable (and in fact very easy) using Postgres.

Comment: I think It's not a good idea to use "TRIGGER" or "LISTEN" from the database to make queries in another web-service, to it's even possible...

Comment: To advance the subject, here is a post that seems useful to me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571924/postgres-trigger-notify-with-php

Comment: I don't like too the idea of using triggers handled by the database. Anyway I'm using MySQL...